# Info based on page title?

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

I'm looking for a way to get info from wikipedia based on the page title.

example: If i have a page called "Britney Spears" i want to be able to get a simple bio extracted from wikipedia onto the page. "age" "height" that sort of stuff.

Comment: Wikidata is for that: [Britney Spears on Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11975) They're interlinked, wikipedia points to the wikidata entry (look for the link Wikidata item [on the left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Spears)) and wikidata points to the different wikipedia articles about B. Spears (scroll to the bottom of the B. Spears page on Wikidata), so that should be an easy task.

Answer (score 3):

From Wikidata API, you could access the data from [Britney Spears entity](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11975) using the [`wbgetentities` endpoint](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities): [`https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&titles=Britney%20Spears&sites=enwiki&format=json&props=claims`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&titles=Britney%20Spears&sites=enwiki&format=json&props=claims)

Then, to access data as age or height, you will need to understand a bit of [how properties and claims work in Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary/en#Claims_and_statements): height will be [P2048](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2048), age will need to be calculated from date of birth [P569](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P569), etc.

If you happen to work in JS, you can use [`wikidata-sdk`](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk) to [parse those claims data to something simpler to work with](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk#simplify-claims-results)

Answer (score 2):

For bios, you can also use the Wikipedia Open Search API, which is more simple than Wikidata :

[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=britney+spears&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=britney%20spears&limit=10&namespace=0&format=xml)

(you could also ask "format=json" instead of xml, but the output will be strangely formated and difficult to parse)

With a software like Open Refine, you could automate the search for a column of page names, like this :

[image: Here is a demo.]

Once the xml extracted, you can parse the descriptions from it with this GREL formula :

```
value.parseHtml().select('Description').htmlText()
```

Comment: **Another solution**

Check if the Wikipedia page has an equivalent in DBpedia, the structured version of Wikipedia :

[http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search/PrefixSearch?QueryClass=&MaxHits=5&QueryString=britney+spears](http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search/PrefixSearch?QueryClass=&MaxHits=5&QueryString=britney+spears)

You can then extract the URI of the resource and parse the informations you want.

The advantage of DBpedia over Wikidata is that it uses property names understandable by a human (for a city, "population" instead of P1082, for example)